# Best practice sending username & password to server from app

Tags: security, webserver, sencha-touch-2

What's the best practice for sending username and password to a webserver from a Sencha developed app?

Is it as easy as the Ext.Ajax function? (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax)

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'validation-username-password.php',
    params: {
        username: Bob,
        password: pass123
    },
    success: function(response){
        var text = response.responseText;
        // process server response here
    }
});
```

Is it anything else I should have in mind? Like safety? Are people able to sniff the username and password between the app (phone) and the webserver if I use the above method?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your credentials are never sent unless you have a secure connection (SSL/HTTPS) and you'll be OK.

Comment: Agree and +1ed. The actual Javascript code doesn't matter as much as the protocol being used (HTTPS is secure, HTTP will invariably mean passwords can be sniffed).

Answer (score 2):

Use Secure Connection and Use `POST` method for sending Credential to server,
if you use `OAuth` or any other Standard Authorization methodology than its good.

Answer (score -2):

Don't send the password as plain text, even if you use SSL, instead send the Hash of the password and also, only store the hash of the password on the server, if possible with a salt. This way, if a hacker gets into the server database where all the hashes of the passwords are stored, he will not get a list of password but a list of hashes with salts which will be useless in most cases. Some times, users use the same password on many sites, imagina if a hacker gets into your server and gets a list of the plaintext passwords, then he has a list that could use to hack into many other accounts at other sites. So using hashes instead of plaintext passwords is a better practice.

**TL;DR** *Send a hash of the password through SSL instead of the plaintext password and don't store a plaintext password on the server, instead store the hash of the password along with a salt.*

Comment: Sending a hash instead of the real password from the client does not help in any way improve security. How to hash is known to an attacker, because he knows the client code. He can also disable hashing there and simply send the hash without generating it from a password first. Nothing will be gained. The important part is the server side hashing. Combined with SSL this is secure enough to prevent against third party sniffing and password recovery in case of a server information leak.

Comment: It does help in some cases. And you just repeated what I said.

Comment: My main point is that I object your proposal of sending the password hashed. This is simply wrong.

Comment: My proposal is sending the user and the password in one hash, along with some salt. But like you said, I could be wrong. If you could please explain in more detail why I'm wrong I would really appreciate it since I'm in the process of doing exactly this. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Another thing. It's possible and fairly easy to do an ARP Spoofing and the use something like SSLStrip to read all the traffic going from and to any computer on a network. If you send the plain password (even with ssl) it could be read with ease. Instead, if you send the hash of the user and password. It would still be read but the attacked wouldn't have your password. He would still be able to access your account from that site but he would not have your password. Some people use the same password for everything, that's the problem. What do you think?

Comment: You assume SSL can be easily circumvented. This is not true - unless the client does not validate the server certificate. Another point: How does the server know that the password is the correct one for the account? If you send a hash, not only does an attacker not get the password, but the server doesn't also. How do you check? And please don't say: The server compares the hash sent with the hash stored. Because that is essentially plain text password storage with no security.